# Setting HTML5 autofocus attribute with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, autofocus

I have a  website that has one input field (like a search engine) and I use the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute on it.

But on very small screen sizes the soft keyboard that pops up on many devices obscures too much of the screen.

Is it possible to se the autofocus attribute in a CSS media query, so its only active on larger displays ?

I know I could set the focus with Javascript, but right now the pages doesn't use any Javascript and I would prefer to avoid it if its possible to use CSS for this.

Comment: If you really don't want to use JS, you could have two inputs (one with autofocus, the other one without it), and show one or the other with media queries. Hidden inputs don't get autofocus ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As suggested above in comments:* Use two inputs and make the one hidden (`display:none;`). Then with a `@media` rule target screens that have a maximum width of `480px` and make the hidden input visible (`display:block;`) and hide the other one.

**CSS**:

```
.smscreen {
  display: none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .lgscreen {
    display: none;
  }

  .smscreen {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

See **[Example using CSS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYRZYL)**.

---

Otherwise, you can detect the window size with jQuery on page load, and if the screen is larger than `480px` to use [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) function on the input.

See **[Example using jQuery](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBOwep)**.

Comment: The jQuery demo does not work. 1. You would also need to do it on page load (So you don't _have to_ resize your window for it to work). 2. It seems that adding the attribute afterwards is not setting the focus. Since we don't care whether or not the input gets focus on window resize (mobile users don't resize their window), you could just `.focus()` it on page load if the screen size is large enough: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBOwep

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Thanks, for the tip. Can I include your pen for the jQuery example?

Comment: Sure you can. But are you sure yours is working for you? I never get focus (even on resize) in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Mine, is working on resize. Open the console and resize the window to see it added and removed.  The reason for not doing anything is a strange one, see [here a working autofocus input](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emXOyo) and compare it to [this here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azMoqb). Mind the spacing where the `type="text"` and `autofocus` in these two. So I assume is appending it like [this one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azMoqb).

Comment: Nice catch! That is really weird indeed. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what it is! I included your jquery solution and removed mine.